# org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome v111

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

I tried to invoke the website using Selenium and Chrome browser v111.

The browser is opening but the website is not invoking.
It is working properly but after updating chrome "Version 111.0.5563.65 (Official Build) (64-bit)" I'm getting this problem:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection
```

I tried,
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552.

This is the code:

```
 package com.testng.library_Files;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 public class one {
     WebDriver driver=null;

     @Test(priority = 1)
     public void DoSetup()
     {
         //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src/main/java/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
         ChromeOptions options= new ChromeOptions(); 
         options.setHeadless(true);
         //driver= new ChromeDriver(options);
         driver= new ChromeDriver();
     }

     @Test(priority = 2)
     public void LaunchURL()
     {
         driver.get("https://www.google.com");
     }
 }
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: what issue? what problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I followed the below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75703971/21386874

```
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
```

I tried but it is not working.
In my project, I got the below error.
Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:49877/devtools/browser/3a3af47d-732a-4337-a91c-18c8ced545cd
> Build info: version: '4.5.3', revision: '4b786a1e430'

Ans:

I downloaded the newest chromedriver.exe with the 111.0.5563.64 version.
Also, I added one more dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And added this code line at the first line into the `@BeforeTest` method:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
```

Answer (score 20):

Using [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) ***v111.0*** this error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:49877/devtools/browser/3a3af47d-732a-4337-a91c-18c8ced545cd
```

and this error message...

```
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3319163Z WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3320374Z java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
```

and even this error message...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.asynchttpclient.ws.WebSocket.sendCloseFrame(int, String)" because "this.socket" is null
```

...is the result of *`devtools_http_handler`* rejecting an incoming WebSocket connection from the http://localhost origin.

---

### Details

This issue is the result of *`Origin`* header when set is being auto-resolved into meaningless value in **Netty 4.x** currently being used by Selenium. This issue was discussed in details in [Origin header is always sent from WebSocket client](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/9673) and was addressed through [Fix generating the Origin header value for websocket handshake request](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/12941).

---

### Solution

As per the [*Selenium Blog*](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/using-java11-httpclient/) there are a couple of approaches to solve this issue.

- ***Using*** [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) ***HTTP Client in Selenium***: Selenium uses an HTTP client and associated WebSocket client for multiple purposes. [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) is an open-source library built on top of Netty. It allows the execution of HTTP requests and responses asynchronously. Additionally it also provides WebSocket support.But *AsyncHttpClient* is no more maintained since June 2021 as *Java 11+* provides a built-in HTTP and WebSocket client. Selenium can utilize it to replace AsyncHttpClient.

  - *Prerequisites*:

    ```
    Project configured to use Java 11+
    Using Selenium 4.5.0 as a minumum version
    ```
  - *Integrating the Java 11+ client*: As Java 11+ HTTP client sits in its own artifact it can be imported into your project that use Java 11+ as follows:

    ```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
  - *Setting the system property*: You need to set the system property to indicate that Java 11+ Http client needs to be used. By default, it uses the *AsyncHttpClient*:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
    ```
- ***Using*** [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) ***in Selenium***: As the ChromeDriver [verbose log](https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/xL5-13_qGaA/m/cGk_5MvTAAAJ) suggests:

  ```
  [32332:259:0214/190812.204658:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(766)] Rejected an incoming WebSocket connection from the http://localhost:58642 origin. Use the command line flag --remote-allow-origins=http://localhost:58642 to allow connections from this origin or --remote-allow-origins=* to allow all origins.
  ```

A quick fix to this issue would be to add the argument *`--remote-allow-origins=*`* as follows:

- *Java*:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  ```

---

### References

Links to useful references:

- [Chrome 111 is not compatible with default HTTP Client](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11750)
- [Issue 1422444: Selenium Chromedriver no longer works with Chrome 111 update](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1422444)
- [DevTools: reject debugging web socket connections with a defined Origin header](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/0154caeefc74530d5cb57ce71608beb1b77bca39)

Answer (score 4):

```
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();    
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");    
//Launching the browser
driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue and found solutions. I added below code then program worked perfectly.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded chromedriver_win32.zip for ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 version & on workspace I added below code.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

After this issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error for different versions and this got resolved for me. The problem might be with the java, selenium and testNG versions compatibility. You can try with java 11 , selenium version as 4.5 or above and testNG version as 7.5

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 117 there is an issue, that could be solved by adding a dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```