# Getting error for selenium - both for chrome & firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have gone through the available issues but not being able to identify the problem. Posting here to get help. OS - windows -10 browser - firefox - 107.0.1 selenium java - 4.8.1

testing for firefox - browser is not launching -

Code:

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; //import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstSeleniumTC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium-java\\chromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\selenium-java\\firefoxDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    
}
```

Console Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-QKEHO5U', ip: '192.168.56.1' at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:157) at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:130) at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:111) at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:101) at demo.FirstSeleniumTC.main(FirstSeleniumTC.java:17) Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver process to start. Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989' System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:218) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:98) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543) ... 6 more
```

For chrome - the browser is launched but the url is not used- showing as - not secure data-

```
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 8431 Only local connections are allowed. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started successfully. Mar 22, 2023 6:43:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92) at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118) at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:54687/devtools/browser/b8f002dc-36c4-48db-8c52-f3943bef0598 Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989' System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.(NettyWebSocket.java:102) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107) at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.(Connection.java:78) at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116) at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:114) at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:82) at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:50) at demo.FirstSeleniumTC.main(FirstSeleniumTC.java:13)
```

Please help. I am a beginner.

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718422/org-openqa-selenium-remote-http-connectionfailedexception-unable-to-establish-w

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome v111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718422/org-openqa-selenium-remote-http-connectionfailedexception-unable-to-establish-w)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZdlSW4S7h4
just add the argument for chrome, it will work. For me firefox issue still exists.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

Answer (score 0):

If you still having error, try adding argument options to ChromeDriver method.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```