# Script is not working after invoking the browser. I am practicing the page object model

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Browser is invoking but other script is not working it is not hitting the URL and etc. I have downloaded the latest exe file of chrome browser and also gives the correct path. but still it is giving file not found at the given path[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BTfw.png)

In other class[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNl8l.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ0RZ.png)

If I am commenting the line System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32.exe"); getting a new error which is below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIk3q.png), but with this atleast browser is invoking only and stuck on the window[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwBx4.png)

script shold be functional and to get the login page

Comment: Refer this -https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7598774 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for the websocket error see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718422/org-openqa-selenium-remote-http-connectionfailedexception-unable-to-establish-w/75741758#75741758