# GoogleChrome version issue while using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, version

I use Google chrome as my browser for Selenium-python based Automation Testing.
I keep getting the below error from time to time:

```
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 115
Current browser version is 117.0.5938.150 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

The version number showing 117 above, it keeps changing each time(based on the updated version).

How can I fix this issue permanently?
I used the following:

```py
 import chromedriver_autoinstaller as chromedriver

 chromedriver.install()

 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

It worked fine for few days, but again this?

Comment: Might this logic works      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718422/org-openqa-selenium-remote-http-connectionfailedexception-unable-to-establish-w/75719759#75719759

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particular about using this library `chromedriver_autoinstaller` to manage your chrome driver, and if you are using latest selenium version(`v4.6.0` or higher), then you can leave it to selenium to download and manage the `chromedriver.exe`. Selenium's in-built tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will do the driver management automatically for you.

Code can be simplified to:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: I tried driver- webdriver.Chrome(), still same issue.
Version of Selenium 4.6.0.

I am trying the below now:
 from chromedriver_py import binary_path # this will get you the path variable
 svc = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=binary_path)
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc)

But now I am getting following error, no idea why it is occurring:

"AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'ChromeService'"